# Gclient runhooks does nothing

Tags: build-process, chromium

I am trying to build chrome on a macbook utilizing the tarball download. Its my understanding that after running `gclient sync --force` (takes 1 hour to complete), that `gclient runhooks` is issued to build the xcode project files. However, runhooks does nothing for me. The command is accepted, but it just returns back to the prompt instantaneously. No error and no result. Did I miss something for building? If anyone is wondering -- Im using this method because I cant use the SVN method.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after a reboot, runhooks ran correctly and generated the xcode proj files. The issue is resolved. Must have been a glitch of some sort.